# Find a mistake in summing a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I was doing one task and i can't find where I'm wrong. I have to find sum $S$ of given series. The answer is  $\frac{1}{8}$.
$$S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(2n-1)^2(2n+1)^2} $$
First $\frac{n}{(2n-1)^2(2n+1)^2} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{(n - \frac{1}{2})^2}-\frac{1}{(n + \frac{1}{2})^2}) $
From this $ S_N = \frac{1}{2}(4-\frac{1}{(N+\frac{1}{2})^2}) $ and $ S = \lim_{N\to\infty}S_N = 2$
Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Does $(2n+1^2)$ mean $(2n+1)^2$?

Comment: Check your steps backwards to find mistakes.

Comment: yes, sorry for mistake

Comment: $$
\frac{n}{{\left( {2n - 1} \right)^2 \left( {2n + 1} \right)^2 }} = \frac{1}{{32}}\left( {\frac{1}{{\left( {n - \frac{1}{2}} \right)^2 }} - \frac{1}{{\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)^2 }}} \right)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gary notes, you've miscounted powers of $2$. Since$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{(n-1/2)^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1/2)^2}&=\frac{2n}{(n-1/2)^2(n+1/2)^2}\\&=\frac{2n(2^2)^2}{(2n-1)^2(2n+1)^2}\\&=\frac{32n}{(2n-1)^2(2n+1)^2},\end{align}$$you're wrong by the expected factor of $\frac{\frac12}{\frac{1}{32}}=\frac{1}{16}$.

Answer (score 1):

Partial fractions $$\frac{n}{(2 n-1)^2 (2 n+1)^2}=\frac{1}{8 (2 n-1)^2}-\frac{1}{8 (2 n+1)^2}$$
telescoping series
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
 s_1= & \frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{72} \\
 s_2= & \frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{72}+\frac{1}{72}-\frac{1}{200}= \frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{200} \\
 s_3= &  \frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{200}+\frac{1}{200}-\frac{1}{392}=\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{392}\\
\ldots & \ldots\\
 s_n= & \frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{8 (2 n+1)^2}\\
\end{array}
$$
as $n\to\infty$, $s_n\to \frac18$